# changing type of a entry in dictionary throws error

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
d = {'today': datetime.today()}
d['today'] = str(d.today)

#AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'today'
```

playing around with the python console I found out that you can't do the above. why is it so?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it saying you don't have 'today' property - 'today' is just a key of dictionary. Change your code:

```
d = {'today': datetime.today()}
d['today'] = d['today'].strftime(<your format>)
```

Comment: oh.. I thought you could access dictionary values by . notation. thanks